# Lisp evaluation aborted on unbound variable

Tags: macros, lambda, elisp, sbcl

During the first example (the database example) in [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), the author uses a macro and a couple support functions in order to replace a larger function, named `where`. The code works fine when `where` is a function, but the macro setup returns "undefined variable" and "unbound variable" errors. (Note that I commented out the original function, restarted Emacs and recompiled my file once adding the `where` macro.)

The caught style-warning in the REPL is most suspect to me since the macro should evaluate with `ROW` rather than `CD`, according to the example. Why is `ROW` unused? How do I resolve this warning?

This is printed in the REPL:

```
; in: SELECT (WHERE :TITLE "Animals" :RIPPED T)
;     (WHERE :TITLE "Animals" :RIPPED T)
; ==>
;   #'(LAMBDA (ROW)
;       (AND (EQUAL (GETF CD :TITLE) "Animals") (EQUAL (GETF CD :RIPPED) T)))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable ROW is defined but never used.

; in: SELECT (WHERE :TITLE "Animals" :RIPPED T)
;     (WHERE :TITLE "Animals" :RIPPED T)
; --> FUNCTION AND IF EQUAL 
; ==>
;   (GETF CD :TITLE)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: CD
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     CD
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

This is printed in the debug space:

```
The variable CD is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

Here are the support functions and macro in my .lisp file:

```
; this function is used in both implementations. *db* is a (global) database
(defun select (selector-fn)
  (remove-if-not selector-fn *db*))

(defun make-comparison-expr (field value)
  `(equal (getf cd ,field) ,value))

(defun make-comparisons-list (fields)
  (loop while fields
       collecting (make-comparison-expr (pop fields) (pop fields))))

(defmacro where (&rest clauses)
  `#'(lambda (row) (and ,@(make-comparisons-list clauses))))
```

I'm using SBCL, Emacs and Slime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that it is an error in the version of Practical Common Lisp that I am using. I discovered this as I was adding to my question a link to the book. The web version has the correct example [here](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html).

It turns out the macro should be defined as follows. It reads `cd` as opposed to `row`:

```
(defmacro where (&rest clauses)
  `#'(lambda (cd) (and ,@(make-comparisons-list clauses))))
```

I didn't realize the lambda function and the function that it calls have to share the variable name (`cd` in this case).

(*I'm not sure if this is considered too localized, but after all this effort I wanted to document it somewhere, so here it is for now.*)